XVBA extension VS CODE : Error in Bootstrap XVBA Config
In XVBA Live Server normally when I press Bootstrap XVBA Config > Create VBA Project, a folder called vba-files should be created, but it is not created in my environment.
1
2 after pressing "Bootstrap XVBA Config"
3 after pressing "Create VBA Project"
I use macbook.
The same situation occurred when I launched VSCode in administrator mode.
